# Overriding PyQt signals in child class

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots

I'm trying to subclass a generic data class to perform some additional operations on the data computed by the parent. I would like to reuse the `dataReady` signal in the subclass. The problem is that the signal is still emitted from the parent, and triggers the connected slot(s) before the additional computations have completed.

Is it possible to override/suppress signals emitted from the parent class, or will I simply have to choose a different signal name?

Here's a simplified example of my classes:

```
class Generic(QtCore.QObject):
    dataReady = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Generic, self).__init__(parent)

    def initData(self):
        # Perform computations
        ...

        self.dataReady.emit()

class MoreSpecific(Generic):
    dataReady = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MoreSpecific, self).__init__(parent)  

    def initData(self):
        super(MoreSpecific, self).initData()

        # Further computations
        ...

        self.dataReady.emit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [blockSignals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#blockSignals):

```
def initData(self):
    self.blockSignals(True)
    super(MoreSpecific, self).initData()
    self.blockSignals(False)
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. However, it appears this method won't extend to further levels of inheritance

Comment: @user3419537. Yes, it does. It will block *all* signals, regardless of inheritance. However, `super` is not designed for calling *specific*  classes in the inheritance hierarchy. For that, you should bypass the computed method resolution order and reference the class directly (e.g. `BaseClass.initData(self)`).

Comment: I realise that, the problem is that the call will also unblock all signals regardless of inheritance, so if I have a child that employs this method, and the parent constructor calls `blockSignals(False)` and emits the signal, then that negates the effect of the call to `blockSignals(True)` in the child's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I would just restructure the classes a bit.

```
class Generic(QtCore.QObject):
    dataReady = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Generic, self).__init__(parent)

    def initData(self):
        self.computations()
        self.dataReady.emit()

    def computations(self):
        # put your computations in a method
        ...

class MoreSpecific(Generic):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MoreSpecific, self).__init__(parent)  

    def computations(self):
        super(MoreSpecific, self).computations()
        # further computations
```

Now your `initData` method, which is supposed to do some calculations and then send a signal, doesn't have to change and your `MoreSpecific` class will only send the signal once.

Comment: I think in my case you are right - a restructuring of the classes is probably the ultimate solution. I accepted the answer from @ekhumoro  though because it answers the question I asked.